# PHP Function Accessing Database Connection

Tags: php, scope

How do I allow a function to access a database connection without using GLOBAL?

config.php

```
 DEFINE ('DB_HOSTNAME', 'hostname');
 DEFINE ('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
 DEFINE ('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
 DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');

 $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

 if(!$dbc) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

functions.php

```
 function something()
 {
 $info = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT info FROM text") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
 }
```

The above gives me the following error:
     mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: Let your ART OF DEBUGGING be groomed, Dont put such errors on Stack man

Comment: The day you'll change you db to mysql, oracle or another one, you'll get stucked with your connection handler. You should use PDO instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use function parameters

```
function something ($dbc) {
  // your db code here
}
```

[function arguments](http://php.net/functions.arguments)

Comment: That gives me the error: Missing argument 1 for something() and mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: Of course you _must_ call the function _with_ the connection handler as the argument!

Answer (score 3):

Either pass the database handle to your function, as @KingCrunch and others have said, or call a function that returns the handle:

In `config.php`:

```
function get_dbc() {
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$dbc) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    return $dbc;
}
```

In `functions.php`:

```
require_once('config.php');

function something()
{
    $dbc = get_dbc();
    $info = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT info FROM text") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
}
```

You may wish to look at [The mysqli Extension and Persistent Connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) for details on how you can prevent the connection from being re-established on each call to `get_dbc()`.  There are alternative approaches to this, such as creating a singleton class for your database connection.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways one is by passing arguments and the other by using function closure like @Ondrej said. But I wonder both of these require you to modify the code if that is the case, then I would suggest you to use `global` keyword.

You can use `global` keyword to get the scope of variable `$dbc`

Try this..

```
function something()
{
   global $dbc;
   $info = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT info FROM text") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
}
```

**(OR)**

Try this...

```
function something()
{
    $dbc = func_get_arg(0);
     $info = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT info FROM text") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbc));
}
```

& do this ....

```
$query = something($dbc);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use global.

Answer (score 1):

its so simple just pass your $conn variable into another calling function(instead of making new connection) like

yourpage.php

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
someFunction ($conn)//you can add other parameters if you like 

function someFunction ($conn) {
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM examples);
}
```

Note:This is not good practice to always make new connection for database access.so always make connection once and use it every where.(but if your requirement different and require multiples connections then you can make multiples connections)

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways. You could use classic procedural style:

```
function something($dbc)
```

or anonymous function (if you use PHP5.3):

```
$fn = function() using ($dbc)
```

Comment: I just showed possibilities. And anonymous function is a possibility in this case - he can use `using`.